# UnsatisfiedLinkError after building with il2cpp for x64 built in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build

I have an Android Unity Project which i build using Unity 2018.4.2f1 which worked perfectly for Mono Scripting with armv4 architecture, but since the new Google Policy states to give arm64 architecture apk for upload, i shifted to il2cpp with arm64 architecture.

The Build succeeded, but after running the project, one of the Plugins which i used seems to throw

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
```

I believe this has something to do with either il2cpp or the arm64 architecture change, because everything was working fine before this change, does anyone know how to resolve this.

Comment: Does the Plugin support that architecture? Did you make the according settings laos in Unity [PluginInspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html)?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, i have emailed the plugin support, but there is no reply so far. i am doing research and scavenging the internet, so far i have found that Android is looking for x64 folder in my plugins, which the plugin does not have. i am looking for a way for android or unity to bypass that

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research here and there and spending almost a day on the internet for this i finally found a workaround for this problem, apparently i was right on point about the x64 part of the question, this was happening because of x64 architecture

to bypass this You need to add the following filters(abiFilters) to your app module’s build.gradle files. So when your device try to run your app, it will check gradle file and understands that it should not generate any folder and use existing native library resources

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }

}
```

Thats it, nothing more was required atleast in my project